# C6 chord followed by Am7

Tags: chord-progressions

C6 chord over D and 3 C notes in right hand, then Am7.  The chords contain the same notes. The proximity to the right hand doesn't allow for rearrangement of chord notes.  Why does the author not just repeat C6?  How is this intended to be played? What is the best transition?

Comment: This is in measure 7 of "What's New" song, from Real Jazz book.

Answer (score 1):

The bass part probably changes, maybe from a C to an A. I agree, the difference is subtle, and hardly worthwhile, especially if the rest of the chord voicing is static.A copy of the sample would give a better clue.

Comment: I am new here. How do I include a copy?

Comment: Sorry, I'm too old to know...  I'll have to dig out my fake books.

Comment: That's fine.  If you have the large Real Jazz book, my question refers to p. 402, "What's New?" Measure 7.  Thank you -  your comment above is helpful. However, I think it sounds better to just repeat C6.  I personally don't like going lower, more bass, with the chord.

Answer (score 0):

That's just for root movement. So, measures 7 ad 8 are:

```
C6  Am7 Dm7  G7
```

The `Am7` leads to the `Dm7` much more naturally that `C6 -> Dm7` would.

Also, right before the `C6` in measure 7 is a `G7` so that resolving to `C6` instead of `Am7` makes a lot of sense as well.

Remember, the strongest root movement in western music is `V -> I`. A good first place to start when figuring out why a certain progression is the way it is, is to look at root movements between chords.

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify, I needing piano chord arrangements.

Comment: I should have, first said, thank you.  Your answer is helping me to realize that I need to back off from specifics and study general chord progression concepts.  My issue is that, I rarely play chords in root position, at the piano.  I alter them for ease of fingering transitions from chord to chord. With the proximity of the right hand, in the above example, I am inclined to play both chords the same way.  I am just learning how to interpret fake music notation.  Are the chords meant to be played as written, I.e. root position? Or do I have the liberty to alter them as I see fit?

Comment: The bass note matters, whether you or another instrument is playing it.  The inversion or voicing of the upper notes doesn't (well it DOES, but the chord symbol doesn't define it).   C, C/E, F  is a quite different effect to C, C, F.    Changing the bass note from C to A gives C6 a very different flavour and function.